# IOS How to convert float array to short array?

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone

How to convert audio float array to short array() ?

Comment: show your code and what you tried

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to encode and decode a float with NSData:

**encoding:**

```
NSMutableData * data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
float z = ...;
[data appendBytes:&z length:sizeof(float)];
```

**decoding:**

```
NSData * data = ...; // loaded from bluetooth
float z;
[data getBytes:&z length:sizeof(float)];
```

**A couple of things to note here:**

1. You have to use NSMutableData if you are going to add things to the data object after creating it. The other option is to simply load the data all in one shot:

   NSData * data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&z length:sizeof(float)];
2. the getBytes:length: method is for retrieving bytes from an NSData object, not for copying bytes into it.

Comment: is any way to convert audio float array to short array ?